# dropping objects in oracle database 12c without generating archivelogs

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

is there any way to drop objects and packages of a schema in ORACLE DB without generating archive logs?

i have a huge schema that is decommissioned. i want to drop all its objects first but it generates a lot amount of archive logs which filled my Fast Recovery Area.

please help if you know any solution to the objects of a schema without generation of archive logs.

i tried to use drop for example: 
*drop package xyz*  it generated a lot of archive logs.

note: 
the database server is holding both active and non active schemas all what i need is to drop the old non active schemas without generating archive logs.

Thank you in advance,
Wissam.

Comment: Are you going to drop the USER too?

Comment: i will drop the user and tablespace at the end but if i execute drop user xyz cascade; it takes ages until it finishes

Comment: Follow up question: why do you care how long it takes? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Follow up Answer: my problem is that when dropping objects the database generate a lot of archive logs during the drop time which filled my FRA and i had to delete backups and files from the FRA to free up some space. it matters for me the time spent executing the drop user as i have deadlines dropping decommissioned servers and database schemas to free up resources.

Comment: Is it possible there is something else at play here.  I fail to see how the dropping of a package creates enough redo to fill FRA.  Table or tables, maybe, but a package?

Comment: it is not only packages got dropped i gave example of what i'm talking about on packages but my question is on all objects. any yes if you have like 20000 package to be dropped and you tail the alert log you will see the frequency of creation of archive logs when dropping packages.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is really going to be `decommissioned` then you can alter the system and set off archive mode at first place and then start dropping the objects.

The method for disabling archive log mode is:

Shutdown edit pfile / spfile (spfile when instance is up ofcourse) to say log_archive_start = false.

startup mount

alter database noarchivelog;

alter database open;

Read more at [here](http://dba-oracle.com/bk_disable_archive_log_mode.htm).

Comment: the database server is holding both active and non active schemas all what i need is to drop the old non active schemas without generating archive logs.

Comment: This information is missing from your question. Please put it for more accurate solution

Comment: thanks the question is appended with this information. sorry i missed mentioning this by mistake.

Comment: Achieve log is set at database level not at schema level. So if you really want to avoid archieve logs then you must folow the above way. I dont think there is any other way.